# To what degree is Charles Darnay’s decision to go to Paris at the end of Book the Second a noble or virtuous decision?

Tags: character-analysis, charles-dickens, a-tale-of-two-cities

I am having trouble with this question from "A Tale of Two Cities." Just wondering if someone could help with this. If anyone could bring up quotes as well, that would be great!

Comment: Ah, whoops. This is a question about Darnay, not Carton.